# Is it possible to check if a value is equal to another in python quickly when referring it to a list?

Tags: python, list, if-statement, tuples

I want to check if an input value is equal a value inside the list without going through every value inside the list.

```
list=('a','b','c','d')
test=raw_input('enter letter')
if test in list:
   if test == a:
         (code)
   if test == b:
         (code)
   if test == c:
         (code)
   if test == d:
         (code)
```

Comment: Probably a good idea *not* to use `list` as a variable name since Python already has its own use for it. Also, in this case you are using the variable `list` with a `tuple` .. could result in more confusion :)

Comment: (1) It's a bad idea to name a variable `list`. (2) what you have is a tuple, not a list. (3) You have a `tuple` of characters - you may as well use a `str`. (4) Your code won't work because the variables `a`,`b`,`c`,`d` have not been initialized. (5) if you're checking against letters, do `if test == 'a'`, etc - but you're better off doing `if test in list`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is better done with a dictionary.

```
def a_code():
    print "a"
def b_code():
    print "b"

d={'a':a_code,'b':b_code}
test=raw_input("enter a or b")
d[test]()
```

Of course, if code is the same in each case, you could do:

```
if test in ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'): #tuple
   do_something()
```

which is functionally equivalent to:

```
if test in ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']: #list slower than tuple -- ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
   do_something()
```

or, more simply:

```
if test in 'abcd': # string
   do_something()
```

Comment: so what happens when I want then to use the what a or b equaled for the first one?

Comment: @fanjojo I moved `raw_input` out of the dictionary, does that address your question?  I'm not completely sure what you're asking...

Comment: sorry it was late and i forgot that it went to the define block to do the coding. :(

Answer (score 2):

This is really a tuple not a list. But yes, you can use the `in` membership test for this.

With a `tuple`:

```
In [1]: mtuple=('a','b','c','d')

In [2]: 'a' in mtuple
Out[2]: True

In [3]: 'z' in mtuple
Out[3]: False
```

Works the same with a `list` too:

```
In [4]: mlist=['a','b','c','d']

In [5]: 'a' in mlist
Out[5]: True

In [6]: 'z' in mlist
Out[6]: False
```

More on the membership test with [in](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#in) toward the bottom of the page:

> The operators in and not in test for collection membership. x in s
>   evaluates to true if x is a member of the collection s, and false
>   otherwise. x not in s returns the negation of x in s. The collection
>   membership test has traditionally been bound to sequences; an object
>   is a member of a collection if the collection is a sequence and
>   contains an element equal to that object. However, it make sense for
>   many other object types to support membership tests without being a
>   sequence. In particular, dictionaries (for keys) and sets support
>   membership testing.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily find the index of the matching item using the `index` method of sequences:

```
choices=('a','b','c','d')
test=raw_input('enter letter: ')
if test in choices:
    index = choices.index(test)
    # do something based on index
```

(I changed the name of the variable named `list` in your sample code to `choices` because `list` is the predefined name of a fundamental type in Python -- besides that, the variable actually contains a tuple of values, not a list of them because they're enclosed in parentheses instead of square brackets.)

The `if test in choices:` tells you quickly if the value assigned to `test` is equal to any of those in `choices`. The `index()` method does essentially the same thing but also tells you the index of which one. One important difference between them is that when the value isn't in the sequence, the `index()` method will throw a `ValueError`, whereas the `in` operator will just return `False` if there's no match.

Since they're so similar, it's uncommon (as well as inefficient) to use them both as shown.

From the rest of your code it looks like perhaps what you *really* wanted to know is a good way of dispatching based on the value of `test`. As many of the other answers indicate, this is often done with a dictionary in Python since it has no `switch` or `case:` statement found in other programming languages.

To add to the other examples, here's a somewhat novel way to build and use one (a dictionary) on-the-fly:

```
def func_a(): pass
def func_b(): pass
def func_c(): pass
def func_d(): pass

test = raw_input('enter letter: ')
try:
    {'a': func_a,
     'b': func_b,
     'c': func_c,
     'd': func_d,
    }[test]()  # call corresponding function
except KeyError:
    # handle other values of test
    ...
```

Another alternative, since the names of the `func_x`'s defined are all global variables, which allows you to avoid even having to build your own dictionary, would be to just use the one returned by the built-in  `globals()` function instead:

```
test = raw_input('enter letter: ')
try:
    globals()['func_'+test]()  # call appropriately named function
except KeyError:
    # handle illegal values of test
    ...
```

Comment: This may be better as a try/except block.  (EAFP vs. LBYL).  e.g. `try: index=choices.index(test);do_something(index); except ValueError; pass`

Comment: @mgilson: I was going to do that then noticed they already had the `if test in choices:` meaning it would never raise.

Comment: globals is an interesting trick (and I'm glad you pointed it out), but I don't like it because 1) It forces a naming convention for the functions which may not make sense and 2) (more importantly), it opens up a hypothetical function "func_e" which might have been created but not meant to be used in this block.  Both are probably not things which would cause problems, but it's good to keep these things in mind (limit your namespace to include only what is needed).

Answer (score 0):

Were you thinking of something like this perhaps?

```
def block_a():
    print "AAA"

def block_b():
    print "BBB"

def block_c():
    print "CCC"

d = {"A": block_a, "B" : block_b, "C" : block_c}

test=raw_input('enter letter: ')

d[test]()
```

Answer (score 0):

While you can do things with dictionaries to emulate a switch statement, for only a few items (4 in this case), there's nothing wrong with using `if` statements

You could use the `elif` statement (short for "else if"), to make it clear only one of the branches will be executed (e.g if it matches "a", there's no point checking c, and d).

Also the initial `if test in mylist:` check seemed redundant in your example code

So it can be simplified to:

```
things=('a','b','c','d')
test=raw_input('enter letter')

if test == "a":
    code("was called with 'a'!")
elif test == "b":
    code("was called with 'b'!")
elif test == "c":
    code("was called with 'c'!")
elif test == "d":
    code("was called with 'd'!")
else:
    # Optional else block, executed if the input wasn't a, b, c or d
    print "Uhoh"
```